# How to make my jQuery script require minimum 8 characters?

Tags: jquery

This is my Script:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
<head>
<title>Registration Form</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {


$('input[tabindex="0"]').focus();


$('#email').blur(function() {
var regexEmail= /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/;
var inputEmail = $(this).val();
var resultEmail = regexEmail.test(inputEmail);
if(!resultEmail) {
    $(this).next('.error').css('display', 'inline');
}
else {
    $(this).next('.error').css('display', 'none');
}
});

$(function() {
var passwordLength = $('#password').val().length;

if(passwordLength < 8) {
    $('#password').next('.error').css('display', 'inline');
} 

});

$('#password').change(function() {
$(this).next('.error').css('display', 'none');
});
});
</script>
<style type="text/css">
.error {
display: none;
color: #FF0000;
font-size: 0.7em;
margin: 0px 0px 0px 5px;

   }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<form name="register" id="registerForm" action="submit" method="post">
<label class="label" for="email">Email: </label>
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" size="48" tabindex="0" />
<span class="error">please enter a valid email address</span>
<br /><br />
<label class="label" for="password">Password: </label>
<input type="text" name="password" id="password" size="48" tabindex="1" />
<span class="error">please enter a valid password</span>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

As it is, if the password input box is empty an error message is displayed.  what I want to do is modify this code so a minimum of 8 characters is required.  I want everything else to remain the same.  Why is it if I do use if(passwordLength < 8) it doesn't work?  I am new at jQuery and just trying to wrap my head around it.  This was an exercise in a book with a challenge to make the password box require a minimum of 8 characters and the obvious thing to me is if(passwordLength < 8) but I see that is not the way it works.  Please shed light.

Comment: Could you please show the version with the `passwordLength < 8` check included? That seems right. (Also, your e-mail validation is wrong; just use `<input type="email">` and don’t worry about a regular expression.)

Answer (score 2):

You've got it.

```
if(passwordLength < 8) { ... }
```

This is correct. You just need to apply it in the right place:

```
$('#email').blur(function() {
    var regexEmail= /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/;
    var inputEmail = $(this).val();
    var resultEmail = regexEmail.test(inputEmail);
    if(!resultEmail) {
        $(this).next('.error').css('display', 'inline');
    }
    else {
        $(this).next('.error').css('display', 'none');
    }
});

$(function() {
    var passwordLength = $('#password').val().length;

    if(passwordLength == 0) {
        $('#password').next('.error').css('display', 'inline');
    } 

}); 

$('#password').change(function() {
    $(this).next('.error').css('display', 'none');
});
```

In this, there are a number of errors:

- `$(function() { ... });` is shorthand for `$(document).ready(function() { ... });`. You don't need it inside a document-ready method.
- You're only checking the email's validity on `blur` - is this deliberate? I'd check it on `change` - instead of `$('#email').blur` use `$('#email').change`
- Use an `<input type="email">` instead of using a regex. Don't reinvent the wheel.
- Indent your code! I've reformatted it in the block above as I read through it. Proper formatting makes your code easier to both read and debug.

I've rewritten the code and simplified it all down to this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

 $('.error').hide();

 $('#email').on('keyup', function() {
  var input = $('#email').val();

  if (input === "" || input.length < 8) {
   $(this).next('.error').show();
  } else {
   $(this).next('.error').hide();
  }
 });
 
 $('#password').on('keyup', function() {
  var input = $('#password').val();

  if (input === "" || input.length < 8) {
   $(this).next('.error').show();
  } else {
   $(this).next('.error').hide();
  }
 });
    
});
```

```html
<body>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="test.js"></script>
    <form name="register" id="registerForm" action="submit" method="post">
        <label class="label" for="email">Email:</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" size="48" tabindex="0" />
        <span class="error">please enter a valid email address</span>
        <br/>
        <br/>
  
        <label class="label" for="password">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" size="48" tabindex="1" />
        <span class="error">please enter a valid password</span>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Actually I didn't write any of it myself.  I was just following a step by step lab and most of it was c/p

Comment: @Doug You were given bad code then. Consider that part of the exercise might have been seeing what you made of it.

Comment: I went ahead and added the entire code from the study guide to give you a better idea.  Even to a newbie like me it seems messy but  am just trying to follow along.  I still can't change it to accept a minimum of 8.

Comment: @Doug - the last paragraph of code in my answer, in a document-ready jQuery clause, should work.

Comment: No, it doesn't seem to work.  Even when i put in a valid email address it still shows an error message and the password does not show the error message if there is less than 8 characters.  I replaced what I had with yours.

Comment: I am using Fiddle to test.  You can test both versions:

https://jsfiddle.net/howie954/9qffy52v/1/

https://jsfiddle.net/howie954/9qffy52v/2/